# Data Grid in C# wpf with custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a class in C# that looks something like that:

```
class Program
{
   string name;
   float number;
   string type;
   Value[] parameters=new Value[40];
}
class Value
{
   float parameter;
   string parameter name;
}
```

Also, I have a `DataGrid` that is supposed to look like this:

first 3 columns are `Number`,`Name`,`Type`. 
The others are 40 parameters names `Value[index].parameterName).`

Each row in the `DataGrid` supposed to represent a `Program` object, and display the 3 properties value `number`, `name` and `type`, followed by the values of the `Value[index].parameter`.

the `Values` size is dynamically allocated, and I'd rather do it mostly in c# code and not in xaml.
Also, I'll need to change the values in the cells (except number).

is there an event that I can implement for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to display each parameter in a separated column, or a single column with all parameters ?

Comment: I assume that by `Value[index].parameter` you mean `parameters[index].parameter`?

Comment: I want each parameter in a different column.
yes,sorry, I meant parameters[index].parameter

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to suggest that you should have List of Value class instead of Array (As your size is not pre-known) like

```
class Program
{
   string name;
   float number;
   string type;
   List<Value> parameters;
}
```

Now you should create DataGridTemplateColumn inside your DataGrid to show your dynamic size parameters like

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Program}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding parameters}">
                          <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                  <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        </ListBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: @ItayAzolayAmsalem From MSDN : _The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class._